# Python pygame.event.get_pressed() not updating

Tags: python, pygame

I have a program that draws a green circle which shrinks, and when you press <kbd>p</kbd>, the circle disappears and a red line appear. But when I press <kbd>p</kbd> again the green circle should reappear, which it don't.

Whenever I call the `pygame.event.get_pressed()` function after I press <kbd>p</kbd> the first time, it always returns the same value. Is there some sort of keyboard reset I have to use in order to get the `get_pressed()` method to read properly again?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)

pygame.init()

size = (700,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screennumber = 1

pygame.display.set_caption("Game Test")

running = True
width = 350

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

screen.fill(BLACK)

pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
print(pressed)

if pressed[pygame.K_p]:
    screennumber = 2
else:
    screennumber = 1

if screennumber == 1:

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,GREEN,[350,350], width,1)

    pygame.display.flip()

    if width>1:
        width = width-1

if screennumber == 2:

        time.sleep(0.25)
        pause = True
        while pause:
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            print(pressed)
            if pressed[pygame.K_r]:
                pause = False

            pygame.draw.line(screen,RED,[0,0],[700,700],5)

            pygame.display.flip()

            clock.tick(21)


pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(21)


pygame.quit()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should the rest of your code (with the exception of the quit) be indented after the block calling `pygame.event.get()`? I'm guessing `pygame.key.get_pressed()` doesn't update until a new event is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pygame.key.get_pressed` is not a reliable method of processing keypresses in real time. The function returns a dictionary with the state of the keyboard at the time of the function call. But, if a key was pressed and released between calls, the dictionary would be the same as if the key had not been pressed at all.
A better way to check if the user has pressed a key is to process `pygame.KEYDOWN` events in your event loop. Then check if the `KEYDOWN` is for the key you want.

Here is a version of your program that is organized into three sections: 1) process events, 2) update the elements of the game, 3) draw to the screen.

```
import pygame
import time

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)

pygame.init()

size = (700,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game Test")

running = True
width = 350
paused = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:

    # process all events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # -- HERE IS THE RELEVANT SECTION --
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused = not(paused)

    # update everything
    if not paused:
        if width > 1:
            width = width-1

    # draw everything
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    if not paused:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,GREEN,[350,350], width,1)
    else:
        pygame.draw.line(screen,RED,[0,0],[700,700],5)
    pygame.display.flip()

    # update the clock
    clock.tick(21)


pygame.quit()
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this code.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.key.get_pressed()` updates when you call one of the event functions. Put `pygame.event.pump()` in your `while pause:` loop and it works as it should. `pygame.event.pump()` tells pygame that you don't want to use the events but that it should handle internal actions.

But currently your program won't respond to any events when the red line is present (you cannot even close the window), so I would suggest having an event loop in your `while pause:` block checking for `pygame.QUIT` events.

Also, if you don't call one of the event functions regularly, the OS will think your program has crashed.

Comment: `pygame.event.get_pressed` gets the state of the keyboard at the time of the function call. It is not useful for checking if the user pressed a key within the last frame because the state of a key that was pressed and released since the last call will still be `False`. Instead, OP should process all necessary events in the event loop.

Comment: Yes, it's often better to use the event loop as described in [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling#t=201702100452096335115).